# For this selection sort, why is the first number 0 when 0 is never used in my array? (in c)

Tags: c, sorting, nested-loops

This is code called by main to sort an array using selections sort in the C language.  I have a file opened in main and put the first ten ints into an array and the 11th into a variable and then a bunch of simple functions are called.  The whole thing is repeated three times.  For my test file, that last two iterations have the correct printed sort, but the first starts with 0, but I don't have a 0 in my array.  It also drops the last int.

Thanks in advance for all your help!!

Here is my code:

```
    void sortme (int arry [], int last_int)
{
     int temp;
     int smallest_int;
     int current_int;
     int target_searcher;
     int numPrinted;

     for(current_int = 0; current_int < last_int; current_int++)
        {
            smallest_int = current_int;

            for(target_searcher = current_int + 1; target_searcher <= last_int; target_searcher++)
                if(arry[target_searcher] < arry[smallest_int])
                    smallest_int = target_searcher;

            temp = arry[current_int];
            arry[current_int] = arry[smallest_int];
            arry[smallest_int] = temp;
        }                                                                       //end outter loop

     numPrinted = 0;

     printf("\nThe sorted array is: ");
     for(current_int = 0; current_int < SIZE; current_int++)
        {
            printf("%4d", arry[current_int]);
            if(numPrinted < COUNT)
                numPrinted++;
            else
                {
                    printf("\n");
                    numPrinted = 0;
                }
        }
     printf("\n");

     return;
}
```

Here is my output for reference (most of the stuff is commenetd out in main.c):

```
The file opened.

Scanned into a[] and target is  33

ARRAY[1]
The contents in the array are:   40  32  57  27  67   6   3  89   2  99
The sorted array is:    0   2   3   6  27  32  40  57  67  89
The value searched,   33, was  not found.

Scanned into a[] and target is   3

ARRAY[2]
The contents in the array are:   86  43  89  32  45  12   1  58  98   4
The sorted array is:    1   4  12  32  43  45  58  86  89  98
The value searched,    3, was  not found.

Scanned into a[] and target is  11

ARRAY[3]
The contents in the array are:    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
The sorted array is:    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
The value searched,   11, was  not found.
Closing the file.
The file closed.
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? try it with a really small array (say, only 1 entry). Step through your `for (current_int = 0; current_int < last_int; current_int++)` loop, compare the contents of the variables to what you expect to be in the variables, and then that should tip you off to why 0 is being stored as the first entry.

Comment: @Raymond is right:  debugging and stepping into code with a debugger is absolutely **mandatory**.   If you don't know how, you must learn.  If you know how, and choose not to, you are wrong.

Comment: Debugging would be the same as adding in printf statements to help see where programs stick?  We haven't gone over debugging in class (I'm very new at programming).

Comment: No class is going to teach you debugging. It's just something you do when something doesn't work. They don't teach debugging in woodworking class either, but when the lid doesn't fit on your storage chest, you need to figure out why. Compare what happens with what you expect at each step of the process and see where reality diverges from your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You allow `target_searcher` to be equal to `last_int` while searching for the minimum. So, sometimes you get a random small value injected into your array (and mess with memory that doesn't belong to you). Of course, I am assuming `last_int` is the length of the array.

When you are dealing with "valid indexes only", the range is from `0` to `len-1`. You can see that with an array of length 1 (in case you are ever in doubt again). Since there is only 1 element, it is at `array[0]`, or `array[len-1]`.

Having said that, it is usually customary to pass parameters as array and length instead of array and index of last valid element. It is more natural. Say, you have a large array with two blocks of `len1` and `len2`, and a function that does something with these partitions. If you use length as parameter, you use:

```
processBlock(arr, len1);
processBlock(arr + len1, len2);
```

If you were to use last valid index, there would be all these `+/-1` terms you'd have to deal with. So it is either:

```
processBlockIdx(arr, len1 - 1);
processBlockIdx(arr + len1, len2 - 1);
```

or:

```
processBlockIdx(arr, lastIdx1);
processBlockIdx(arr + lastIdx1 +1, lastIdx2 - lastIdx1 - 1);
```

As for the answer of your second question: yes, the problem was caused by accessing an element that is outside the bounds of your array. Since C doesn't have the safety net of checking array bounds, an error like this usually manifests itself as an unexplained value appearing in your results, or worse, an application crash. In some cases you are not as lucky, and it manifests the problem in a completely unrelated part of your program. So, it is best to be *very* sure about array element accesses.

Comment: I have last_int passed from main as the size of the array, 10.  So should I pass it as 1 less than the array size (pass 9 for last_int)?

Comment: I tried that and it worked!  I'll try the same with a few of the other functions that I had to write.  Is the reason that it injects a random number is because I have exceeded the array bounds (i.e. I was in element 11 of an array of only ten elements)?

Comment: @Piseagan The answer will be somewhat long, so I am editing my answer to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks, that helps tremendously!